# How would I solve the following error "readline() on unopened filehandle ..."?

Tags: perl, file-io

How would I solve the following error:

```
readline() on unopened filehandle UPPER at faStat2 line 86.
```

in the following code?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

...

my $cmd = $0;
$cmd =~ s#.*/##;

($#ARGV > 0) || die "Usage $cmd <tibcoUpperMDLog> <tibcoLowerMDLog> <outFile>\n\n";

open(my $UPPER, $ARGV[0]) || die "Unable to open $ARGV[0]\n";
open(my $LOWER, $ARGV[1]) || die "Unable to open $ARGV[1]\n";

...

while ($msg = <UPPER>) { getUpperBusTimeStampAndBatchSize(\$msg); } #This is the line that the error is complaning about
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I include both practical and stylistic chages.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

...

my $cmd = $0;
$cmd =~ s#.*/##;

die "Usage $cmd <tibcoUpperMDLog> <tibcoLowerMDLog> <outFile>\n\n"
  unless @ARGV > 2;

open my $upper, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open $ARGV[0]\n";
open my $lower, '<', $ARGV[1] or die "Unable to open $ARGV[1]\n";

...

while ($msg = <$upper>) { getUpperBusTimeStampAndBatchSize(\$msg); }
```

Practical:

- 3 arg `open` (safer, modern)
- fixed consistent use of indirect filehandles

Stylistic:

- using `or` rather than braces and `||` (least important)
- compare against `@ARGV` rather than `$#ARGV` (more readable, "need at least 2 args")
- use lower case on lexical (`my`) variables

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need to use `$UPPER` inside the `while` loop:

```
while ($msg = <$UPPER>) ...
```

Some [references](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/perlfile.shtml) use non-dollar-sign variables for file handles in examples, but they also `open()` without the `$` in the handle name. It's confusing if you ask me, but just stick with one or the other and I believe you'll be okay.

Comment: Bareword file handles are an old feature.  For modern code, you should use lexical file handles (like `$UPPER` rather than `UPPER`).  You should also use the 3-argument version of `open`.  See [this article](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try `while ($msg = <$UPPER>)`, if you name the filehandle $UPPER in the open() you have to use the same variable name when talking to the filehandle later too.