# readline () unopened file handle error in Perl

Tags: perl, filehandle

I'm having trouble fixing an error in my code. I'm trying to get the code to read the input file and pull out only what is between the `[]`. However, the error I am getting is a `readline() on unopened filehandle`... I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly here for the `while ()` file handle.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

my $file = '';
my $newfile = '';
open($newfile, '>', 'newmyosin.fasta') or die "Can't create file", $!;
open($file, '<', 'myosin.fasta') or die "Can't open file", $!;

while(<$file>) {
        print;
        chomp;
        if ( $_ =~ /\[(.+)\]/ ) {
                $file = $1;
        }
}
```

So, for example:

This would be what one part of my input file would look like:

```
>gi|115527082|ref|NP_005954.3| myosin-1 [Homo sapiens] 
>gi|226694176|sp|P12882.3|MYH1_HUMAN RecName: Full=Myosin-1; AltName: Full=Myosin heavy chain 1; AltName: Full=Myosin heavy chain 2x; Short=MyHC-2x; AltName: Full=Myosin heavy chain IIx/d; Short=MyHC-IIx/d; AltName: Full=Myosin heavy chain, skeletal muscle, adult 1 [Homo sapiens] 
>gi|119610411|gb|EAW90005.1| hCG1986604, isoform CRA_b [Homo sapiens]
MSSDSEMAIFGEAAPFLRKSERERIEAQNKPFDAKTSVFVVDPKESFVKATVQSREGGKVTAKTEAGATVTVKDDQVFPM
NPPKYDKIEDMAMMTHLHEPAVLYNLKERYAAWMIYTYSGLFCVTVNPYKWLPVYNAEVVTAYRGKKRQEAPPHIFSISD
NAYQFMLTDRENQSILITGESGAGKTVNTKRVIQYFATIAVTGEKKKEEVTSGKMQGTLEDQIISANPLLEAFGNAKTVR
NDNSSRFGKFIRIHFGTTGKLASADIETYLLEKSRVTFQLKAERSYHIFYQIMSNKKPDLIEMLLITTNPYDYAFVSQGE
ITVPSIDDQEELMATDSAIEILGFTSDERVSIYKLTGAVMHYGNMKFKQKQREEQAEPDGTEVADKAAYLQNLNSADLLK
ALCYPRVKVGNEYVTKGQTVQQVYNAVGALAKAVYDKMFLWMVTRINQQLDTKQPRQYFIGVLDIAGFEIFDFNSLEQLC
INFTNEKLQQFFNHHMFVLEQEEYKKEGIEWTFIDFGMDLAACIELIEKPMGIFSILEEECMFPKATDTSFKNKLYEQHL
GKSNNFQKPKPAKGKPEAHFSLIHYAGTVDYNIAGWLDKNKDPLNETVVGLYQKSAMKTLALLFVGATGAEAEAGGGKKG
GKKKGSSFQTVSALFRENLNKLMTNLRSTHPHFVRCIIPNETKTPGAMEHELVLHQLRCNGVLEGIRICRKGFPSRILYA
DFKQRYKVLNASAIPEGQFIDSKKASEKLLGSIDIDHTQYKFGHTKVFFKAGLLGLLEEMRDEKLAQLITRTQAMCRGFL
ARVEYQKMVERRESIFCIQYNVRAFMNVKHWPWMKLYFKIKPLLKSAETEKEMANMKEEFEKTKEELAKTEAKRKELEEK
MVTLMQEKNDLQLQVQAEADSLADAEERCDQLIKTKIQLEAKIKEVTERAEDEEEINAELTAKKRKLEDECSELKKDIDD
LELTLAKVEKEKHATENKVKNLTEEMAGLDETIAKLTKEKKALQEAHQQTLDDLQAEEDKVNTLTKAKIKLEQQVDDLEG
SLEQEKKIRMDLERAKRKLEGDLKLAQESTMDIENDKQQLDEKLKKKEFEMSGLQSKIEDEQALGMQLQKKIKELQARIE
ELEEEIEAERASRAKAEKQRSDLSRELEEISERLEEAGGATSAQIEMNKKREAEFQKMRRDLEEATLQHEATAATLRKKH
ADSVAELGEQIDNLQRVKQKLEKEKSEMKMEIDDLASNMETVSKAKGNLEKMCRALEDQLSEIKTKEEEQQRLINDLTAQ
RARLQTESGEYSRQLDEKDTLVSQLSRGKQAFTQQIEELKRQLEEEIKAKSALAHALQSSRHDCDLLREQYEEEQEAKAE
```

Out of this, I would like to create a new file "newmyosin.fasta" which will pull out the organism name within the brackets in the header for this sample (e.g. `[Homo sapiens]`. The Perl code is used to read in from the myosin.fasta file with multiple samples as above, pick out the name within the bracket `[]`, and write out to a new file (e.g. newmyosin.fasta).

Thanks!

Comment: You're setting your filehandle to an empty string at the start, and then you're re-assigning it to a string in your loop. Don't do that.

Comment: Then what would you suggest I do to fix the code?

Comment: Use a different variable to store the result of the regex match. I can write up a proper answer later.

Comment: Can you include some sample input and expected output? Check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: Pull out the text within the brackets, and put it where? Should the other lines without brackets still be included? Have you tried the code I posted in my answer?

Comment: You should never get that error with this code. If the open fails, the program should die. If not, it is not unopened. Either this is not the code you actually used, or you removed something from it.

Comment: I wanted to pull the text within the brackets and write it to the new file I was creating. No, other lines without brackets should not be included. Yes, I tried the code you had posted in your answer. It didn't pull what I wanted it to pull. I wasn't able to get it to write properly in the file.

Comment: Also, this is the entire code I used. I have not removed or edited it in any way.

Comment: Oh lol, I just realized that you did this: `$file = $1;`, That's not good

Comment: Missing `use strict;`.

Comment: Without sample output, it's impossible to know what you're looking for. In general, when you're asking for help, you want to make it easy for other people to help you, not excruciatingly difficult.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I solve the following error "readline() on unopened filehandle ..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8748891/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$file = $1;
```

You overwrite your file handle. Then you can no longer read from it. And you will get the error mentioned.

You should of course save the match somewhere else, e.g.:

```
my $match = $1;
```

And probably also print it:

```
print $newfile $match;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589678/readline-unopened-file-handle-error-in-perl#comment54955614_33589678), you're re-assigning your filehandle to the capture group in the middle of reading the file. Since you opened a separate file for output, I assume you want to print the matching strings to that file instead.

Having said that, your requirements are pretty vague, your sample input doesn't look accurate, and you didn't provide any sample output, but if I understand your intent correctly, I think this is what you want:

```
my $file = 'myosin.fasta';
my $tmp = "$file.tmp";

open(my $new, '>', $tmp) or die "Can't open $tmp: $!";
open(my $old, '<', $file) or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$old>) {
    if (/\[([^]]+)\]/) {
        print $new "$1\n";
    }
}

close($old);
close($new);

rename($file, "$file.bak");
rename($tmp, $file);
```

Contents of myosin.fasta after running the script:

```
Homo sapiens
Homo sapiens
Homo sapiens
```